# Jetpack compose initial set of items very slow and not smooth scroll

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have LazyColumn that gets list of posts. When I start scrolling initially it is very glitchy and slow. But when I pass for example 10th item in list it works super good without any glitch. Do not know what cause scroll issues on start. Here is my list

```
@Composable
fun LazyListState.OnBottomReached(
    onEndReachedThreshold: Int = 0,
    onLoadMore: suspend () -> Unit,
) {
    require(onEndReachedThreshold >= 0) { "buffer cannot be negative, but was $onEndReachedThreshold" }

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        snapshotFlow derivedStateOf@{
            val lastVisibleItem = layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.lastOrNull()
                ?: return@derivedStateOf true
            lastVisibleItem.index >= layoutInfo.totalItemsCount - 1 - onEndReachedThreshold
        }
            .collect {
                if (it) {
                    onLoadMore()
                }
            }
    }
}

@Composable
fun TileListView(
    tiles: List<Tile>,
    loadMore: suspend () -> Unit,
    onEndReachedThreshold: Int = 0,
) {

    val listState = rememberLazyListState()
    val tileViewModel: TileViewModel = hiltViewModel()
    LazyColumn(
        state = listState,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(5.dp),
        modifier = Modifier.background(Style.colors.appBackground),
    ) {
        items(tiles, key = {
            it.id
        }) { tile ->
            tileViewModel.tileViewFactory.ConstructTileView(tile)
        }
    }

    listState.OnBottomReached(onEndReachedThreshold) {
        loadMore()
    }
}
```

Tried also release mode and all recommendation but still start is very slow. Any idea maybe what can cause issue?

Comment: read about state hoisting in compose, and try to move view model to root screen

Comment: This viewmodel does not provide any data. It just provides one function to render view so do not know can this be actual issue?!

Comment: what does this line do             tileViewModel.tileViewFactory.ConstructTileView(tile)

Comment: Render UI. 
object TileViewFactoryImpl : TileViewFactory {
    @Composable
    override fun ConstructTileView(tile: Tile?) {
        return when (tile) {
            is MediaTile ->
                MediaTileView(tile)
            is ConversationStarterTile ->
                ConversationStarterTileView(tile)
            else -> {}
        }
    }
}

Comment: should not be in view model, add a new composable in ui, named TitleView(MediaTile)

Comment: Nah it is not reason. Same behaviour it has. Laggy on start.

Comment: Have u found a solution?